# How to fit a mixture of Gamma distributions to the PMF of a discrete distribution?

Tags: distributions, curve-fitting, gamma-distribution, scipy

I have a PMF of some discrete distribution that has been numerically computed.
Note that I do **not** have any *samples* to work with here, so techniques like Maximum-Likelihood and Expectation-Maximization don't apply. I only have the PMF of the discrete distribution itself, which is simply a long, nonnegative vector whose components sum to 1.

The discrete distribution looks reasonably well-modeled as a mixture of *N* gamma distributions (*N* is known). What's a reasonable way to go about fitting the mixture to it?

The only way I can think of is to hand-code my own coordinate- or gradient-descent algorithm, but it seems too much effort (both on my part and in terms of the amount of computation necessary). Is there a better way?

(While not necessary, a SciPy or MATLAB/Octave example could be extremely helpful. I'm hoping for a method I can code myself in a language like C++, but I realize that might not be practical, so I'm interested in other approaches as well.)

---

Some example data as requested, in case it helps:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.00000378547917956
0.000254067618914
0.00156479688482
0.0044414187977
0.00881560818165
0.0150067507346
0.0250934783012
0.0364480196843
0.0446846535887
0.0481736403324
0.0473452833494
0.0436535252283
0.0387132874982
0.0337816696454
0.0295972032879
0.0267001698978
0.0279827988189
0.0362165748226
0.0486471989886
0.0602335084185
0.0672898116143
0.0684179033513
0.0641605623675
0.0561730620339
0.046373159578
0.0363756352803
0.0272651661276
0.0196061621026
0.0135630878889
0.009043229377
0.00581909570544
0.00361712103199
0.00217346975615
0.0012631914959
0.000710408159256
0.000386756023978
0.000203892354011
0.00010411799478
0.0000515137355117
0.0000246996739328
0.0000114793542013
0.00000517223941954
0.00000225965576783
0.000000957343112229
0.00000039337449953
0.000000156784391692
0.0000000606172441131
0.0000000227362899619
0.00000000827373414225
0.00000000292123458756
0.00000000100077057752
0.000000000332677663195
0.00000000010731171507
0.0000000000335905747662
0.0000000000102032826632
0.00000000000300759417371
0.000000000000860422844084
0.000000000000238586927992
0.0000000000000640598685209
0.0000000000000160982338571
0.00000000000000432986979604
0.0000000000000008881784197
0
0
```

Comment: A mixture of gammas is continuous, not discrete. Do you want the result to be continuous or discrete?

Comment: @Glen_b: Continuous -- i.e., the PMF I have looks like a discretization (of uniform interval) of a mixture of Gamma distributions, so I'm trying to find the mixture whose discretization approximates my PMF best.

Comment: If you're checking a discretization of the gamma (as you say at the end there), isn't your aim to get a discrete result at the end? Or is that only the way you're thinking to check its fit, and you're still planning to use it as continuous?

Comment: Was the pmf you have obtained by dividing observed counts by a total count (even if you won't know such counts), or in some other fashion?

Comment: @Glen_b: No, there are no observations here. The distribution is deterministic and given, obtained through other means not involving samples. I'm working with discrete distributions the whole time, but I'm trying to see how well they might fit a mixture of Gamma distributions, and depending on what I see I'll decide what to do next.

Comment: How long is this vector? One cheap and dirty approach would be to do multinomial sampling with this vector of probabilities enough times to form a data set, and then apply some standard approach. You could even do some 'smoothing' on the values by adding in normally distributed noise if you felt worried about underestimating variance.

Comment: If you're working with discrete distributions the whole time, why would you prefer to approximate with gammas which you then discretize, rather than say a mixture of negative binomials or some-such? There are numerous possible approaches. For example, one might try to minimize a KS-type statistic, or a chi-square-like statistic, or a KL-divergence-like quantity. One might quantile-match, or moment-match. There are more criteria than you could point a stick at.

Comment: @Matthew: A few thousand elements, and I have thousands of such vectors that I may need to run this later on (depending on how well they seem to fit the data overall).

Comment: @Glen_b: Compression is one thing; it would let me compress a vector of a few thousand elements down to one of just a handful of numbers. Or possibly even re-sample it for later use, if needed. If the data fits extraordinarily well I might even try to find conditions under which the distribution ends up approximating a Gamma distribution, but these are all later stages I haven't figured out yet. It really depends on what I end up seeing.

Comment: How does a mixture of Negative binomials inherently result in less compression than a mixture of gammas? They're both two-parameter distributions. In any case, either can be fitted in a variety of ways, some of which I already mentioned. Matthew's idea of sampling would also work, of course.

Comment: @Glen_b: The compression there isn't an issue, it's because the discretization is derived from continuous distributions and represents a real-world phenomenon, and in very special cases the discretization is in fact a gamma distribution. I'm just trying see if it's a good approximation in other cases where it's not exact.

Comment: The thing with @Matthew's suggestion is that I'm trying to avoid resampling this distribution because the whole process is deterministic, there's really no reason to add randomness anywhere.

Comment: The sampling suggestion was aimed at giving you a way to use a standard distribution fitting procedure. If your intent is not to introduce randomness, then you could take a 'deterministic sample' from your vector. Write every element of the vector to the $n$th decimal place. Then take $10^n$ values with frequencies in proportion to the vector elements (vector slot is 0.328? then that corresponding value is taken 328 times). Then you have a 'data set' to work with standard models (violating some assumptions of course).

Comment: @Matthew: Deterministic "sampling" is still "sampling". The entire point of the question was to avoid going the sampling route, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question in the first place. Are you really saying there's no standard procedure for doing this directly without some kind of sampling?

Comment: I can't comment on the existence of other algorithms, but your situation does seem odd to me. Obviously there are ways to connect dots on a scatter plot but I don't know of a way to do that while also fitting a distribution (this may just be a lack of familiarity). Unless you find a common approach for your situation then I would think it would be useful to consider ways to adapt preexisting techniques, and this kind of 'sampling' (it's not really sampling or random at all) would do the trick.

Comment: @Matthew: It's not really that odd. Here's a really simplified example. Take 2 arbitrary continuous RVs, truncate them to make them nonnegative, and now compute the pointwise max() of their distributions and renormalize. Do the same thing for another pair of distributions, and add the two random variables together. The result has no known closed-form solution except in general -- so the convolutions are done discretely -- but it can be reasonably approximated by continuous distributions in certain cases. I don't want to go into more detail, but avoiding samples is really not unreasonable.

Comment: Mehrdad - your opposition to sampling seems strange. The process of fitting a mixture of gammas will be at best an approximation - and the cdf estimates will be (necessarily) biased. As long as the sampling error is substantially smaller than the error in approximation, what substantive difference does a comparatively tiny (unbiased) additional error make? It's like being unconcerned if you had an estimate of the mean that was 105.01 when it should be 100, but then being adamantly bothered about whether it was 105.03 or 104.99 instead of 105.01... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... Now there are ways to fit distributions that don't involve sampling, but they won't necessarily give you a more satisfying outcome than taking a nice big sample and using ML.

Comment: @Glen_b: It's not about the bias, it's about the arbitrariness and the reproducibility. The result simply *has **no reason** to depend* on how the data is sampled (whether it's determined a priori or whether it's actually random), simply because there's no reason to add some degree of arbitrariness or randomness to something that's otherwise completely deterministic, predictable, and un-arbitrary. The result must be a function of the input data, it's as simple as that.

Comment: @Glen_b: If you can convince me it's actually *necessary* then obviously I have no choice, but to me that is impossible because there necessarily exists a unique optimal fitting, and I have yet to see any evidence in support of the conjecture that actually finding that optimal fitting is intractable in most/all cases.

Comment: @Glen_b: To put it into perspective, the sampling scheme you're pushing for is just as silly as trying to estimate the covariance of some sample dataset by repeatedly trying Gaussians of different covariances to "empirically" find the ML estimate of the covariance, even though there's a clearly unambiguous and deterministic method of finding the sample covariance in that doesn't need any of that and gives an exact answer.

Comment: You say there's a unique optimal fitting. You must then have a function in mind you want to optimize (or it could not be unique, since different optimands would give different estimates). Why not state it, and give us a problem to actually solve, instead of leaving us to guess what you want to optimize?

Comment: @Glen_b: I've been looking to minimize total absolute deviation, but I'm open to hearing other ideas if those functions might be significantly easier to work with (like least squares, etc.)

Comment: @Glen_b: I'm not even sure if it's a statistics question in the first place, but I posted here since it seemed like something that would come up in statistics.

Comment: I am completely confident it counts as a stats question. When you say total absolute deviation/least squares/etc, what are you looking at deviation in? The discrete pmf, the cdf, something else? Is there probability at 0 in the discrete pmf? One concern I have is that you'll get good (relative)  fitting at the high frequencies, but possibly terrible fits (in % error terms) at low frequencies. Still least squares should make for a relatively simple job in something like R or Matlab.

Comment: PS a toy example (with some of the features of real data) might help, say a few dozen elements. Not crucial, but if you can manage it, it would assist.

Comment: @Glen_b: Sure, [here's one on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/cwy4T1QR). Regarding the absolute deviation, I meant the deviation of the PMF from the discretization of the continuous PDF. I'm not sure what you mean by "frequencies" here, but the PMF at or near zero is definitely zero if that's what you mean.

Comment: I was asking whether the discrete pmf has any probability at 0. It sounds like it doesn't. It might have affected some of the approaches I was thinking about, but since it doesn't, it's a non-issue.

Comment: 3700 rows $\neq$ "a toy example" with "a few dozen elements", but a real example is also good. I was hoping for something that could be posted in your question, so that it stood alone. Still, thanks, that will be handy. What $x$-value does the first row correspond to? What $x$-value does the second value correspond to?

Comment: @Glen_b: Yeah I didn't have any handy with a few dozen elements, I'd have to bucket them together and add them up haha. Maybe I'll do it in a couple of minutes. The values start at x = 0.

Comment: @Glen_b: I bucketed together every 32 elements and posted it in the question. :)

Comment: Are you seeking to fit shifted gammas, or only zero-origin gammas?

Comment: @Glen_b: Great question... the thought was in my head too. Thinking about it more, I think they would be actually shifted gammas, but I believe I can calculate the amount of shift beforehand through a much simpler computation process, so in reality we can assume the origin is at some fixed/convenient location like the x = 0 or x = 1, so we don't need to optimize over it. Which means we can still assume the PMF is zero at the origin if we'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a vector of numbers $[0, 1, 2,\ldots,M - 1, M]$ with probabilities of seeing each of those value, all of whom sum to 1. You want to find a mixture of $N$ gamma distributions to represent the discrete probability mass function. That being said, what may be the simplest thing to do is to minimize the distance (e.g. squared error) between the empirical discrete PMF and the mixed continuous PMF at that point. You can "estimate" the mixed continuous PMF at $n$ as the average of the mixed continuous CDF at $n - 0.5$ and $n + 0.5$ with the data point at 0 being estimated as value at $0.5$.

Here is an R function example for a mixture of two gammas which assumes that the parameters are passed to it as a list of 5 values ($p, \alpha_1, \theta_1, \alpha_2, \theta_2$) and the Data is a dataframe or matrix of size $M$X$2$ with the PMF. It converges rather slowly, but as you're estimating mixtures anyway, it may get you close to what you want.

```
Dist <- function(pars, Data){
  p <- pars[[1]]
  A1 <- pars[[2]]
  T1 <- pars[[3]]
  A2 <- pars[[4]]
  T2 <- pars[[5]]
  X0 <- pmax(Data[, 1] - 0.5, 0)
  X1 <- Data[, 1] + 0.5
  PMF <- Data[, 2]
  PMF_C <- 0.5 * (p * (pgamma(X0, shape = A1, scale = T1) + pgamma(X1, shape = A1, scale = T1)) + 
            (1 - p) * (pgamma(X0, shape = A2, scale = T2) + pgamma(X1, shape = A2, scale = T2)))
  return(sum((PMF - PMF_C)^2))
}
```

Pass that into an optimzer like `nloptr` and let it rip.

Comment: I don't know r, but from reading it, it seems like you're just using a general-purpose nonlinear optimizer over the vectors (which could do gradient descent or something else), right? (Similar to [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)?) I guess that works (+1), but I was hoping for something more insightful and possibly faster than just plugging it into a generic black-box solver.

Comment: Yup, I'm using a general purpose optimizer to minimize the square distance between the empirical PMF and the "manufactured" PMF created by mixing the gammas.